# String matching with foreach loop in php

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5

I am trying to match two strings using `foreach` loop in php ( laravel framework).

```
$c_act = "ABC123";
foreach ($codes as $cd) {
      $ac = $cd->Code;       //ac holds our Activity code

      if ($ac==$c_act) {
           $act_id = $cd->ID; 
        }
}
```

here `$codes` holds data from my values with `ID` and `Code`.Its

```
 [{"ID":"7","Code":"ABC-1"},{"ID":"8","Code":"ABC-OBT"},{"ID":"12","Code":"ABCD"}]
```

If the first variable is not a match, then I need to go back to foreach loop and start with the next value I have. I tried, But couldn't complete it.

How to do this using php?

Thanks in advance

Comment: simply you can user in_array() function

Comment: @PradyutManna - Look at the question, he got an array with objects. in_array won't cut it...

Comment: @Anant - That doesn't really answer his question?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson there is a function get_object_vars() that convert object to array

Comment: @anat That's what I had tried, but, it fails go back for next value, if the first is not a mactch

Comment: @PradyutManna - Sure, there are a lot of functions in PHP. But that wasn't what you suggested.

Comment: @Sachith  you need to show your input data then

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
$act_id = null;
$c_act = "ABC123";
foreach ($codes as $cd) {
    $ac = $cd->Code;       //ac holds our Activity code
    if ($ac==$c_act) {
        $act_id = $cd->ID;
        break;
    }
}

if($act_id === null){
    // there was no match
}else{
    // there was a match, and the ID is stored in $act_id
}
```

Comment: @Sachith i have added one

Comment: @Sachith i don't see any reason why your code shouldn't already work